# How can I extract elements from a bracketed list?

Tags: r

I currently have a dataset with elements such as

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2), bracketedList = c("[235.223,636.11115,7453.773]","[2355.66377,6362.1645,7633.7473]"))
```

I am wondering how I can extract the first number (`235.223`, `2355.66377`) before each comma in an element in `bracketedList`, the second column, and so forth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `readr::parse_number` which will return the first number from `bracketedList`.

```
readr::parse_number(df$bracketedList)
#[1]  235.2236 2355.6638
```

To extract all (or any) the data from the string you can read the data as json.

```
cbind(df[1], do.call(rbind, lapply(df$bracketedList, jsonlite::fromJSON)))

#  id        1         2        3
#1  1  235.223  636.1111 7453.773
#2  2 2355.664 6362.1645 7633.747
```

Comment: If I also wanted to obtain the 2nd, 3rd, etc element, is there a way to specify that? Thanks!

Comment: In that case a better option would be to read the data as json using which you can get all the values in separate columns.

Answer (score 2):

This could also help you:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(ext = str_extract(bracketedList, "(?<=\\[).*?(?=,)"))

  id                    bracketedList        ext
1  1     [235.223,636.11115,7453.773]    235.223
2  2 [2355.66377,6362.1645,7633.7473] 2355.66377
```

Or in base R:

```
gsub("^\\[(?<=\\[)(.*?)(?=,).*", "\\1", df$bracketedList, perl = TRUE)

[1] "235.223"    "2355.66377"
```

In case you would like to extract all the numbers:

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(ext = str_extract_all(bracketedList, "[^,\\[\\]]+")) %>%
  unnest_wider(ext) %>%
  rename_with(~ gsub("\\.\\.\\.(\\d)", "\\1", .), contains("."))

# A tibble: 2 x 5
     id bracketedList                    `1`        `2`       `3`      
  <dbl> <chr>                            <chr>      <chr>     <chr>    
1     1 [235.223,636.11115,7453.773]     235.223    636.11115 7453.773 
2     2 [2355.66377,6362.1645,7633.7473] 2355.66377 6362.1645 7633.7473
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `base R`

```
cbind(df, read.csv(text = gsub("[][]", "", df$bracketedList), header = FALSE))
```

-output

```
 id                    bracketedList       V1        V2       V3
1  1     [235.223,636.11115,7453.773]  235.223  636.1111 7453.773
2  2 [2355.66377,6362.1645,7633.7473] 2355.664 6362.1645 7633.747
```